# Ionic 2 with WooCommerce API

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, request, ionic2

I am having problems in handling GET/POST requests with WooCommerce API in Ionic 2. Can anyone suggest a way how to do it?

I have tried it using code from this link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/woocommerce-api-npm-implementation/49753/7 
But it shows a runtime error of OAuth Not Defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use woocommerce-api which has already implemented all what you need to authenticate and use the WooCommerce Rest API but since it is a Node.js module that was meant to be used in a Node.js environment and not inside the browser you need first to transform it to a browser library with browserify .Here is a [tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/woocommerce-ionic-2/) to build an Ionic 2 app for WooCommerce using woocommerce-api package

Comment: While the link you provided gives insight, I read through the tut and found out it is incomplete. There is n part 2. For a newbie who does not know how to go about things, this would then be the end of the road. However, since you seem to trust the author I presume you know how to complete this. Is it possible for you to pretty please provide a link to a complete tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Add this.

```
declare OAuth: any ;
```

Answer (score 0):

use https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api
It is a Node.js wrapper for the WooCommerce REST API. Easily interact with the WooCommerce REST API using this library.
I think by using this package and some setup on the server, you can easily connect your application to the server